# PlayFramework apply Evolutions from ClassLoader

Tags: java, playframework

I try apply custom Evolution from ClassLoader as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaTestingWithDatabases#Custom-evolutions). My code:

`Evolutions.applyEvolutions(database, Evolutions.fromClassLoader(CollectorTest.class.getClassLoader(), "testdatabase/"));`

My custom script in directory "test/resources/testdatabase/evolutions/default/4.sql". But evolutions not work. 
Scripts 1.sql, 2.sql, 3.sql in directory "conf/evolutions/default" work correctly. 
If I execute the script like this:

```
Evolutions.applyEvolutions(database, Evolutions.forDefault(new Evolution(4, myUpScript, myDownScript));
```

all works fine.

How to apply custom Evolutions from .sql script correctly?

Comment: i am facing the same issue that if i pass evolutions directly it works fine, but not reading from directory. How did you fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because the Evolutions class is present in two different packages and the example doesn't give much info on that. Below works for play 2.7.3 & scala 2.11:

```
play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions.applyEvolutions(database, play.db.evolutions.Evolutions.fromClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader(), "testdatabase/"));
```